# AngularJS - Angularitics plugin, how to use analytics-on="EnterKey"?

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angulartics (http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/) and I am using the following snippet:

```
<a href="#!/{{match.label}}" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="click" analytics-category="our page" analytics-label="clicking on {{match.label}}">
  <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span> -
  <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.name_abbrev | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>    
</a>
```

This works great when people click on the search result, but what I want is "analytics-on="click | EnterKey"

Is there an EnterKey event OR do I have to use ng-click and then call a function?

Comment: how about trying out: `analytics-on=("'click' | '$event.which === 13')` ? ..$event might be tied to ng-keyup, ng-click or similar though..let me know what happens

Comment: you may not need the single quotes around 'click' and '$event...' from the previous comment.